# UPDATE datetime in SQLite with python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, datetime, python-datetime

I have to insert datetimes in my SQL column using python but when I try to insert a string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS SQLite gives me this error -sqlite3.OperationalError: near "11": syntax error -

the column is now in TEXT format (I also tried DATETIME) but it doesn't seem to accept it, the only format it accepts is YYYY-MM-DD.

This is my code:

```
            for i in range(len(actualValue)):
                attuale = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                c.execute('UPDATE alarm SET valoreAttuale = {} WHERE alarmId = {} '.format(actualValue[value], value + 1))
                c.execute('UPDATE alarm SET raiseDateTime = {} WHERE alarmId = {} '.format("2020-09-28 11:10:45", value + 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [python sqlite3 api doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

> You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack

Another good argument for using [placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) is this example. If the second sql was written *without* `format`, it would look like this:

`UPDATE alarm SET raiseDateTime = "2020-09-28 11:10:45"`. But `format` is "consuming" the quotes (`"`) so the UPDATE query *thinks* it's got a number (2020-09-28 evaluates to a number after all) after that the sql syntax falls apart. The query can be "fixed" by adding the appropriate quotes in the appropriate place. I suggest, instead, that placeholders be used becuase it is a recommended style and a very good habit.